# Stopping hotlinking from subdomains

Tags: .htaccess, hotlinking

We serve images from both our www. and img1/2/3 subodmains.  The rule we have successfully blocks hotlinking from the www. but not the img1/2/3.  Two part question: Why do the img1/2/3 not work when the www does and is there a way to economize this into one rule?

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img1\.)?domain.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img2\.)?domain.org [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img3\.)?domain.org [NC]
RewriteRule \.(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use the `OR` flag in the first three conditions or, alternatively, collapse the three conditions into one.

**`OR` flag:**

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(www\.)?domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img1\.)?domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img2\.)?domain\.org [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://(img3\.)?domain\.org [NC]
RewriteRule .(jpg|jpeg|png|gif)$ - [NC,F,L]
```

**Collapse into one condition**

```bash
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^http(s)?://((www|img(1|2|3)\.)?domain\.org [NC]
```

Comment: That collapsed version was exactly what I needed.  Thank you so much.